Establishing an absolute world coordinate system
I am currently working on a project using the HoloLens 2, where I create a primitive that offsets a spatial anchor in a certain direction and distance received from a client socket I have in my scene. However, I am having problems with the coordinate system. Each time I open the application on the HoloLens, the coordinate system changes based on the direction I am standing since the headset is always taken as the origin. I am struggling to figure out how to establish an absolute coordinate system that I can use and stay consistent inbetween scenes. 
I was looking at the MRTK documentation and found the World Locking Tool (WLT), and I am curious if this may be my solution. I was curious if anyone else has experience with WLT, especially for this type of application, or knows another possible way to establish an absolute coordinate system between sessions.
This is where I was looking for the WLT - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/spatial-anchors-in-unity?tabs=wlt

For your scenario, WLT is indeed the best choice. Before using WLT, I recommend reading World Locking Tools documentation | Microsoft Learn.

Thanks for your confirmation. I am going through the tutorial now, but I am confused on how to utilize WTL for a coordinate system. Does WLT have its own coordinate system that I can use in my Unity project?
